# Ebay API - How do I get item info for out of stock items

Tags: ebay-api

I'm trying to get item information by searching my ebay store. For example, if I enter this URL, it will search my store for a specific keyword and return info about the item.
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SECURITY-APPNAME=MYAPPID&keywords=MYKEYWORD&itemFilter.name=Seller&itemFilter.value=MYEBAYUSERNAME

However, if an item's quantity goes to zero, the item is no longer visible in my ebay store and therefore, won't show any data.  How can I get data for all items, even if they are out of stock?

Please note:  the data I need to get is the ebay auction number (itemID)

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using the finding API for this as opposed to the Trading API? This just seems like a task for GetMyeBaySelling

Comment: I don't care which API as long as it works.   The url I was using works just fine for what I was doing.  I could enter a keyword and get back the itemID.  That's what I need to do.  Now I need to do the same, but even if the item has a 0 quantity and is not showing up in a search.  I don't necesssarily have to use a keyword.  All my items have a unique custom label, so if there's a way to use that, that would be fine also.   I'll look into GetMyeBaySelling, but I'm not an expert.  If you have any code that will work, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I looked into the GetMyEbaySelling feature.  I don't think this will work.  It does get data for everything in the Active List (which includes items with a zero quantity) but I'm not sure it will work.  Here's the ideal situation for me...  ebay allows sellers to assign a "custom label" to any item they sell (like a product code or SKU)  Each item I have listed has a unique 6 digit custom label.  I need to enter a single custom label and get back the itemID associated with that custom label.   Anyone have any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Ho do you manage your stock?

Answer (score 0):

If you are listing using the API then "custom label" on the front end of eBay is actually the SKU node in the API. Here is a list of API calls that utilize this node: [`<SKU>`](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/types/SKUType.html)

So if you want to pull one item at a time, all you need to do is use is use the [**GetItem**](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetItem.html) trading API request. Instead of passing in `<ItemID>(string)</ItemID>` pass in `<SKU>(string)</SKU>`, and you will get the ItemID in the return output xml.

But, this is if you want to pull each item one at a time. There is a limit on how many API calls you can make a day.

So, I would suggest using **[GetMyeBaySelling](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetMyeBaySelling.html)** every so often to download all of your items and store the output to a database. The output for GetMyeBaySelling includes `<ItemID>(string)</ItemID>` and your custom label as `<SKU>(string)</SKU>`.

At this point you can write a little front-end WebPage or APP to pull the data you want from the database.

Comment: This was a nice try, but I kept getting an error saying my SKUs don't exist.  I looked into why, and found this....In GetItem, SKU can only be used to retrieve one of your own items, where you listed the item by using AddFixedPriceItem or RelistFixedPriceItem, and you set Item.InventoryTrackingMethod to SKU at the time the item was listed. (These criteria are necessary to uniquely identify the listing by a SKU.).... Since I didn't set my tracking method to SKU at the time of listing, it won't work.

Comment: Did you try the alternative, pull your items with GetMyeBayselling ?